# pysnmp: How to set SysUpTimeInstance to something else than 0 when using sendNotification for sending snmp trap

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp, mib

I have some equipment that can send snmp traps for alarms etc. I need to simulate this equipment for testing purpose. The output from the tester must be exactly like the output from the equipment but I need to control values etc. I have created a Python script using pysnmp and sendNotification for this. It seems to work fine. However the DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance is send automaticaly by sendNotification and the uptime is always 0. How can I set this value to something else? I know I can put an extra object in the addVarBinds but this will just give an extra object with another value. The initial sysUpTimeInstance  is still 0.
pysnmp                             4.4.12
pysnmp-pyasn1                      1.1.3
pysnmp-pysmi                       1.1.10
pysnmplib                          5.0.21

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

iterator7 = sendNotification(
    SnmpEngine(),
    CommunityData('public', mpModel=1),
    UdpTransportTarget(('localhost', 162)),
    ContextData(),
    'trap',
     NotificationType(ObjectIdentity('NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB', 'netSnmpExampleNotification')).addVarBinds(ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB','netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate'), 1))
)

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(iterator7)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
```

The object used in the above are just examples. I have a another MIB file with the correct objects.
The above example will result in the following received:
`DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00    SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = OID: NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleNotification  NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate = INTEGER: 1`
I am receiving snmp traps with snmptrapd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `pysnmp-lextudio` package, the following code should work,

```py
import asyncio
from pysnmp.hlapi.asyncio import *

async def run():
    snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()
    # Example of how you might update sysUpTime
    mibBuilder = snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.mibInstrumController.mibBuilder
    sysUpTime, = mibBuilder.importSymbols('__SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysUpTime')
    sysUpTime.syntax = TimeTicks(12345)  # Set uptime to 12345

    trap_result = await sendNotification(
        snmpEngine,
        CommunityData('public', mpModel=1),
        UdpTransportTarget(('localhost', 162)),
        ContextData(),
        "trap",
        NotificationType(ObjectIdentity('NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB', 'netSnmpExampleNotification')).addVarBinds(ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB','netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate'), 1))
    )
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = await trap_result
    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication)

    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()


asyncio.run(run())
```

No guarantee if you are using other `pysnmp` packages.